# onPageSelected called instatly on viewPager.setCurrentItem

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

For my project i use swipeable tabs to navigate between lists.
When deleting one of these lists, i would like to have a smooth animation and try to archive this by using `viewpager.setCurrentItem(page, true);` to first switch to another page, before deleting the list.
I then try to catch the event after switching page to delete the list with a `OnPageChangeListener`.

My problem is that it seems like the `onPageSelected(int position)` is called before the animation is complete.

Here's the code :)

Where i start the animation:

```
case R.id.menu_clear_lists:
int pageAmount = sectionsPagerAdapter.getCount();
if (pageAmount < 2)
return false;
int page = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
int newPage = page == 0 ? page + 1 : page - 1;
deleteOnChange = true;
deletePage = page;
viewPager.setCurrentItem(newPage, true);
return true;
```

The eventhandler:

```
if (!deleteOnChange)
    return;
deleteOnChange = false;
Resource.deleteList(deletePage);
sectionsPagerAdapter.destroyItem(viewPager,
viewPager.getCurrentItem(),
sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(deletePage));
sectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope someone has the solution for my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

If you look at the ViewPager's OnPageChangeListener you'll see a onPageScrollStateChanged method. If you override that on your listener you can wait for it to send a "SCROLL_STATE_IDLE" as the parameter, this means that the page has settled and is in a resting state. Be careful though because if the user starts a scroll but doesn't actually go to a new page you'll get settling and it'll be on the current page. You might want to use both onPageSelected and onPageScrollStateChanged to keep track of whether the page turned, then if it's done turning.

Comment: I was browsing around and just saw this question. One of the things to also keep in mind is that you may receive the `onPageSelected` call before or after the `IDLE` remark in the other method.